# Ubuntu 13.04 x64 Flash Player Problems

Tags: 13.04, flash, adobe

I am somewhat new to the linux system, and just installed Ubuntu 13.04 x64 on this pc. The support for all the devices made me happy, but not having flash with firefox presented a problem. I've been trying to debug this problem for about 2 days now, as this computer is my nieces and I'm setting it up for her by Saturday. I have installed chrome as an alternative, so here is what I've tried so far.

As per my search, I've installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras:

```
sudo apt-get ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Checked "canonical partners" as software source and updated all repositories. After doing this (twice in most cases) I researched what else I can do and found the error `flashplugin-installer: Depends: libnspr4-0d` sprang up many results. Among them was the possibility that inside the deb(sp?) the entry `libnspr4-0d` was misspelled and should be `libspr40d`.This is the only option I've yet to try, as it seemed very complicated to carry out.

Installing Adobe flash via software manager or via sudo apt-get returns this same error, and yet I've read that some people have had success in ubuntu 13.04. Is there anything I'm missing?

tldr: I've tried every researched solution except altering the depository for adobe, should I just give up and live with chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP who posted the answer in his question:

> UPDATE:: After doing some searching on the adobe site, I found the following link http://ubuntuguide.net/install-adobe-flash-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04both-3264-bit Upon completing the steps in this tutorial, flash now works in firefox! \o/ Please post this up as additional steps to try if anyone else is having this problem.

Comment: Please change this to be a Community Wiki post, as this isn't really *your* answer.